# How to create and send excel file from server to client in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

For sending CSV file I have done this and it is working fine

```
        @app.route('/downloadFile' , methods=['GET'])
        def downloadFile():
            csvList = [[ 's' , 12], ['r' , 20 ]]
            csvHeader = [['name', 'age']]
            si = StringIO.StringIO()
            cw = csv.writer(si, delimiter=',', quotechar=':', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            cw.writerows(csvHeader)
            cw.writerows(csvList)
            print(si.getvalue())
            output = make_response(si.getvalue())
            output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=report.csv"
            output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
```

But when I am doing the above solution in excel format it does not work, the data format is invalid

```
    @app.route('/downloadFileExcel' , methods=['GET'])
    def downloadFileExcel():
    csvList = [[ 's' , 12], ['r' , 20 ]]
    si = StringIO.StringIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si)
    cw.writerows(csvList)
    print(si.getvalue())
    output = make_response(si.getvalue())
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=report.xls"
    output.headers["Content-type"] = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

on client-side

```
<a id="Link" href="/downloadFileExcel" >
  <li id ="excel">Excel</li>
</a>
<a id="Link" href="/downloadFile" >
<li  id="csv" > CSV</li>
</a>
```

Comment: You can use this lib to create excel file https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Comment: i have used https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/ but this doesnt work for me ??

Comment: it will be helpful if you suggest me how to implement xlsxwriter in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

This sample of code right data into xlsx file

```
@app.route('/downloadFile' , methods=['GET'])
def downloadFileExcel():
    csvList = [['s', 12], ['r', 20]]
    name = uuid.uuid4()
    writer = xlsxwriter.Workbook("/tmp/%s" % name)
    worksheet = writer.add_worksheet()
    for i, row in enumerate(csvList):
        worksheet.write_row(i, 0, row)
    writer.close()

    f = open("/tmp/%s" % name, 'rb')
    output = flask.make_response(f.read())
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=report.xlsx"
    output.headers["Content-type"] = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    f.close()

    return output
```

be carefull to change your header content type to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Best regards

Comment: what I need to send on client-side like in make_response() what I need to send

Comment: and I can't give the specific path of file name because its dynamic data coming from the backend

Comment: issue not solved with this code I am getting                                               config: {transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", adapter: ƒ, …}
data: {status: 404}
headers: {content-length: "15", content-type: "text/html; charset=utf-8", date: "Thu, 12 Dec 2019 17:51:35 GMT", server: "Werkzeug/0.15.6 Python/2.7.16", vary: "Cookie"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object

Comment: How do you make the request ? (I open the url in the browser it works well)

Comment: i am making request on href= "http://localhost:8000/auth/downloadFile" and my controler in auth folder thats why i am giving auth on url

Comment: i am able to make file and send it to client using differant approach but by using xlsxwriter